# Best way to determine if a user went offline in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So my script currently forces the user to send a "ping" every 10 minutes. This inserts a record into MySQL with the user ID and the current timestamp.

What I would like to achieve is seeing if any of the users went offline recently.
In theory that would be selecting a recently online (20ish minutes ago) user, then checking if there has not been a ping in the past 11 minutes except I don't seem to be able to figure out how.
This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM status WHERE time > (CURTIME() - 1200) AND time < (CURTIME() - 660)
```

I have to add, I do this in combination with PHP but that shouldn't really matter.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to do an insert with each ping?  Why not do an update instead?  It would then be trivial to determine who went offline recently (and you'll save a lot of space, and improve DB performance as well).

Comment: You don't need MySQL for that, use session variable in combination with JavaScript to send message to application (something like "I'm alive" with time-stamp) and every x minutes check for difference between time-stamp and current time.

Comment: Yes, but the history is not saved if you perform only updates.

Comment: @Madbreaks the reason I do this with each ping is because I want to keep a history.

Comment: @K4timini Well, that's why I asked. op didn't specify in his/her question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like that :

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), MAX(s.time)) AS duration, s.user
FROM status s
GROUP BY s.user
HAVING duration > 660 AND duration < 1200;
```

If the username is not stored in the status table. You should perform a JOIN between Status and User.

You can use a BETWEEN statement if you want to check duration for a specific range too.

**EDIT :** Thanks to Madbreaks about the "recently" constraint. You can add a AND duration < xxxx to do not retrieve old durations and keep only "recent" status in your result set.

Comment: Your sql is invalid - at the very least, `TIMEDIFF` takes two arguments

Comment: That was a typo. It calculates the time between now and the last ping, for each user. The having instruction gives the ability to filter results on the calculated duration field.

Comment: I like this approach, but you need to limit the duration to get "recently" offline.  Otherwise this will return users that "ever" went offline. Something like `HAVING duration > 3600 AND duration < 3900`

Comment: Yes you can limit with a BETWEEN instruction. Otherwise, if a user never send ping it won't be referenced in the status table so it won't be selected.

Comment: Right.  op said, *"What I would like to achieve is seeing if any of the users went offline recently."*

Comment: The question is what means "recently". Haha ! I updated my post about your answer. (: The big deal is how to do that if you want to keep in mind the history. LOL ! (For example if he wants to check a user send ping regularly and recently)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  Here's one, assuming you have a primary key called `id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM status
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM status
    WHERE time > (CURTIME() - 660)  // was on within last 5 minutes
) sub ON
    sub.id = status.id
WHERE
    time > (CURTIME() - 1200)  // was on within last 20 minutes
    AND sub.id IS NULL;        // was on within last 20, but not last 5
```

Answer (score -2):

Use between for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM `status`
WHERE (`time` BETWEEN (CURTIME() - 660) AND (CURTIME() - 1200))
```

Comment: This only tells you that the user was/wasn't on during that interval.

Comment: @Madbreaks you're right. I should have read more carefully the question.